# Unity Mirror Network Transform not working

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking

I am having an issue with Mirror's network transform component in unity. Players cannot see each other move, and in the inspector window only the host's player moves (this is not updated to the connected player though). In the inspector window you see a sphere moving and facing in the direction of the connected player (I did not program this so it must be Unity trying to tell me something) as per the picture below. [image: Notice the grey ball moving in the left screen (The grey ball in the right screen is just a placeholder for the player's hand, ignore that)]

Any help is much appreciated as there doesn't seem to be anybody that I can find online with a similar problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include all the information we need to reproduce this problem if we start from a new, empty project. That includes how you've configured all the relevant components.

Comment: Hey! I'm pretty far into the project so I don't know if it's possible for me to send you everything, but essentially I have the player movement script on a model from Mixamo, and have given it the network identity and the network transform scripts.

Comment: Then make a new project and copy over only what you need to reproduce the problem, then describe that. You're in a much better position to narrow down the possible causes than we are, since you have access to your whole game to test.